# Image being displayed in ImageView is smaller than the source image

Tags: java, android

I am using an AsyncTask to download an image from the internet and display it in an ImageView. For my app, the image URL is retrieved using an API call and I'm using it to display in the ImageView. It works, but the image is really small and hard to see. I don't know if this is because the image is not stored in the drawable or if I'm missing something in the code. Why is it resizing my image?

Size of the image in my app

[image]

Actual size of image

[image]

**RecipePage.java**

```
Results result = new Results();

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipeviewer, container, false);

        new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_image))
                .execute(result.getURL()); //getURL() just contains the URL of the image
        return rootView;


    }

    class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

**fragment_recipeviewer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recipe_image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm probably missing something obvious or doing something silly. Any solutions please?

Comment: which emulator did you use

Comment: @PhanVănLinh just the in built one for Android Studio

Comment: I mean, which emulator?, samsung s6, nexus 5, or ...

Comment: @PhanVănLinh it is a nexus 5

Answer (score 0):

Update your layout file.

There are multiple options for scaletypes. choose whatever is best for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/recipe_image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is:
The Nexus 5(the emulator that you use) have the resolution is : **1080 x 1920** pixels
And ([your image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKIms.jpg)) have resolution is: **350 × 233** pixels
So your image will look small but it display correct

If you want to increase image size you can

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@id/img"
    android:layout_width="150dp" // modify your width 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

But remember, if you display a small image on a bigger view, you will have a bad image quality
Hope this help